# Grid of all elements of an arbitrarily sized matrix in Julia

Tags: arrays, iterator, grid, julia

I have an `n*m` sized array `A`, and I would like to create a grid of its elements. The output should look something like:

```
B = (A[1,1], A[2,1]
     A[1,1], A[2,2]
     ...
     A[1,1], A[2,m]
     A[1,2], A[2,1]
     A[1,2], A[2,2]
     ...
     A[1,2], A[2,m]
     ...
     A[n,1], A[n,m])
```

My first approach would be to do something like this:

```
A = [1 5;
     2 6;
     3 7;
     4 8]

B = collect(Iterators.product(A))
```

However, this only returns

```
4×2 Matrix{Tuple{Int64}}:
 (1,)  (5,)
 (2,)  (6,)
 (3,)  (7,)
 (4,)  (8,)
```

Instead of the desired output above.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not super clear what the specification for the output grid is. It looks like each element is paired with every element of the next row (`A[1,1]` paired with `A[2,1]` to `A[2,m]`) but the final `A[n,1], A[n,m]` doesn't conform to that pattern. For the example `A` matrix you've posted, can you show what the actual desired output is?

Comment: This question is cross-posted from here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/grid-of-all-elements-of-an-arbitrarily-sized-matrix/89024

Comment: As @DNF already stated, I asked the question also in Julia discourse, because I wasn't sure where I would get the answer quickest. @DNF already answered it there.
@SundarR: OK, here is an example: `A = [1 5; 2 6; 3 7; 4 8] `
And the result should be:
 `B = [1 5; 1 6; 1 7; 1 8; 2 5; 2 6; 2 7; 2 8; 3 5; 3 6; 3 7; 3 8; 4 5; 4 6; 4 7; 4 8;] `

Comment: If the goal is to do some operations on the grid, you can avoid constructing it explicitly. E.g. `using Einsum` and then `@einsum dist[i, j] := sqrt(A[i, 1]^2 + A[j, 2]^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

It was already answered by @DNF here:

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/grid-of-all-elements-of-an-arbitrarily-sized-matrix/89024/3

The essence of it:
This works for any matrix, but here is an explicit example:

```
A = [1 5;
     2 6;
     3 7;
     4 8]
```

The solution is:

```
Iterators.product(A[:, 1], A[:, 2]) |> collect
```

Resulting in

```
4×4 Matrix{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 5)  (1, 6)  (1, 7)  (1, 8)
 (2, 5)  (2, 6)  (2, 7)  (2, 8)
 (3, 5)  (3, 6)  (3, 7)  (3, 8)
 (4, 5)  (4, 6)  (4, 7)  (4, 8)
```

If you do not want to specify each column explicitly:

```
Iterators.product(eachcol(A)...) |> collect
```

In case you prefer a long vector instead of the above result, redefine it as a vector:

```
Iterators.product(eachcol(A)...) |> collect |> vec
```

The three dots are the splat operator, which "unpacks" the result of `eachcol(A)`.

Answer (score 0):

Noone on the **discourse.julialang.org** link suggested:

```
hcat(repeat(A[:,1], inner=size(A,1)),repeat(A[:,2], outer=size(A,1)))
```

giving:

```
16×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  5
 1  6
 1  7
 1  8
 2  5
 2  6
 2  7
 2  8
 3  5
 3  6
 3  7
 3  8
 4  5
 4  6
 4  7
 4  8
```

Comment: I benchmarked a generalization of this: `reduce(hcat, (repeat(@view(A1[:, i]), inner = size(A1, 1)^(i-1), outer = size(A1, 1)^(size(A1, 2) - i)) for i in axes(A1, 2)))` when OP posted the expected output, and found that it performs worse than DNF's version for all but the smallest `A` matrices.

Comment: `hcat((repeat(@view(A1[:, i]), inner = size(A1, 1)^(i-1), outer = size(A1, 1)^(size(A1, 2) - i)) for i in axes(A1, 2))...)` performs somewhat better, but still significantly worse than the original answer.

Comment: @SundarR Worse performance not surprising. But clarity seems a bit higher, so worth a mention.

Comment: It's a pretty neat solution yeah, directly translating the repetitions we visually see in the output, and showing off the flexibility of combining`inner` and `outer` repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way could be:

```
julia> [Iterators.product(eachcol(A)...)...;]
16-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 5)
 (2, 5)
 (3, 5)
 (4, 5)
 (1, 6)
 (2, 6)
 (3, 6)
 (4, 6)
 (1, 7)
 (2, 7)
 (3, 7)
 (4, 7)
 (1, 8)
 (2, 8)
 (3, 8)
 (4, 8)
```